# Textarea to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, wysiwyg

I have a simple `<textarea>` element which I would like to convert links (www.google.com, msn.com, etc) and new lines `(\r\n)` into HTML code.

I have one library which is able to convert links into `<a hrefs>`.
I have another library which is able to convert newlines into `<br>`s.

**Here is the tricky part.**

AngularJS has a directive which converts Strings into html `< div ng-bind-html` however I do not want a user's input to be converted into html, only the new lines and links.

For example, if a user inputs Hi my name is `<b>`John Doe`</b>` I do NOT want the `<b>` tags to be converted into HTML.

Any help? I'm trying to avoid using WYSIWYG as these usually come with more than what I need.

Comment: So it should replace newlines with `<br>`, and it should wrap urls in `<a>` tags. Should it strip other HTML? In your example, `<b>John Doe</b>` would become `John Doe`

Comment: Almost, the <b> tags should remain there but not get converted to HTML. This is for a simple comment page where I want links and new lines to work but not have code executed when rendered.

Comment: You may also want to see: [Linkify](http://soapbox.github.io/linkifyjs/) "Linkify is a JavaScript plugin for finding links in plain-text and converting them to anchor tags."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to HTML-escape the user content before running those libraries that create HTML tags.

This ensures that the only remaining HTML tags are those created by your code.

Comment: Would a DIV set to contenteditable do that automatically (as opposed to using TEXTAREA)?

Comment: @Roberto: No; that would allow arbitrary HTML.

Comment: I tried this simple fiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/m9skxz5L/ and it appears that the browser escapes the HTML automatically. How can the user enter arbitrary HTML? Thank you, I am just trying to understand better.

Comment: @Roberto: Try hotkeys like Ctrl+B, or pasting in formatted HTML